Swaymsg not focusing window
I have switched from i3 to Wayland and everything works fine except for a script I wrote some time back.
The script uses i3-msg to focus on a window via it's class name or id (from i3-msg tree).
Sway has the command swaymsg -t get_tree which does the same thing as in i3.
With the command I can extract the id, app_id, window, pid or any other data from the command line with the command
swaymsg -t get_tree | jq -c -r '..|try select(.focused == true) | [.id]' | tr -d "[]"

(Depending on the attribute, .id will of course be replaced by the correct query).
When I try to use the container information to focus on a specific window with
swaymsg for_window -r [id=10] focus

nothing happens, even though I have checked the id to be the right one.
Due to the -r option, swaymsg even outputs (the flag has no effect on the fact that nothing happend):
[
  {
    "success": true
  }
]

so there does not seem to be any error.
I have tried multiple parameters, from other sources I have read that app_id seems to be the way to go in Wayland when interacting with windows or containers via swaymsg, but nothing happens.
I have also tried the command with different programs like terminals or browsers, nothing changes.
In the manual of swaymsg it also says to put quotes around the command, but that doesn't help either.
Since I don't receive any errors, I am puzzled how to debug.

Although the post is already quite old, someone else might stumble across the same question, as I did.
Apparently, focus does not work with for_window but simply via <criteria> focus. Also, you might need to use con_id instead of id.
From man 5 sway:

id can only be used with xwayland views

So the complete command would be:
swaymsg -r [con_id=10] focus

